# any way to provide a success message in addition to response data in web api rest?

Tags: .net, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Is there a way to provide a success message in addition to response data in web api rest?  Basically, 200 would be returned along with the data collection but is there a way to include an additional text message along with the data collection?

Comment: Can you show some implementation of your `WebAPI` controller/action and data collection that you mentioned?

Comment: You can change reason phrase (OK), you can have some text message, every status code has reason phrase https://urivalet.com/reason-phrases/

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own custom header.

e.g. HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("MyStatus", "This is very successful");

Comment: This makes the client app must parse the headers :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try like the following way:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]string value)
{
        // do something...

        var response = new
        {
            Success = true,
            Message = "Hello from Web API Controller",
            // other data...
        };
        return Ok(response);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

more better option to be create a filter and registering it

```
  public class addSuccResponse : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {

        switch (context.Request.Method.Method.ToLower()) {

            case "post":
                context.Response.Headers.Add("serverMessage", "post message);
                break;

            case "put":
                context.Response.Headers.Add("serverMessage", "put message");
                break;

            case "delete":
                context.Response.Headers.Add("serverMessage", "delete message");
                break;

        }

    }
}
```

then registering it to webapiconfig if you want to apply to all api's else use as a attribute

```
  config.Filters.Add(new addSuccResponse());
```